# I want to return KeyError not None

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to return `KeyError` but instead it returns `None`. I do not understand why.

```
if index == self.length or self.slots[index]==None:
    raise KeyError
```

Comment: @AndrewLi The `()` and message are optional, it's also "correct" to raise the exception class *shudder*.

Comment: Are you aware that "returning" a KeyErrror and "raising" a KeyError are very different things? From what you've posted, I can't tell if you are in a function or not, but you cannot "return" something if you are not in a function.  You may want to edit your question to provide more details about what exactly you are trying to accomplish here

Answer (score 0):

You don't **raise** a `KeyError` because you don't enter the `if`-branch. And you don't enter the `if`-branch because none of your conditions is `true`.

You probably need to adjust your condition if the test-case (that you haven't shown!) should really raise the `KeyError`.

To debug this issue you can insert some `print`-statements:

```
print(index, self.length, index==self.length)
print(self.slots[index], self.slots[index]==None)
if index == self.length or self.slots[index]==None:
    raise KeyError
```

or use a debugger of your choice.

However some comments:

- Normally you want to check if the index is `>=` to the length (that includes `==`!).
- You should compare to `None` using `is`. `None` and `NotImplemented` are guaranteed singletons.
- Use an Exception message in `KeyError`, for example `raise KeyError('index out of bounds or item is None! Try again.')`
- Functions that don't have hit an explicit `return` will return `None`. That's probably why your code returned `None` instead!